# jinja var not passed to template

Tags: django, jinja2, login-required

In my tiny Django webapp, I have 4 or 5 views/pages.  I added authentication on each function, prefixing it by `@login_required()` .

On all pages, I'm able to display the `user.username` variable with Jinja2.

But only on one page (displaystats.html), the user variable is not found or empty ...

Here is my view :

```
@login_required()
def displaystats(request):
    try:
        listpackages = Packages.objects.all().order_by('-id')
    except:
        listpackages = None

    try:
        listprojects = Projects.objects.all()
    except Projects.DoesNotExist:
        listprojects = None

return render_to_response('displaystats.html', {'listpackages': listpackages})
```

Templates are simple : 
- displaystats.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <!-- Head -->
  {% include 'head.html' %}
  <body>
    <!-- Navbar -->
  {% with "Dynamic Packages Statistics" as namepage %}
      {% include 'navbar.html' %}
  {% endwith %}
...
...
```

navbar.html :

```
<!-- Navbar -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'webgui.views.homepage' %}"> MyAPP </a> <p class="navbar-text">{{ namepage }}</p>

{% if user %}
    <p class="btn btn-default navbar-btn pull-right" style="margin-right:15px;"> Welcome, {{ user.username }} </p>
    <a href="{% url 'logout' %}" class="btn btn-danger navbar-btn pull-right" style="margin-right:15px;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"> Logout </span></a>
{% else %}
    <p class="btn navbar-btn pull-right" style="margin-right:15px;"> Welcome, you're unlogged </p>
{% endif %}
```

I tried to comment some of lines (HTML, change jinja2 'if', ... )  but the displaystats.html page don't know the 'user' variable and I don't understand why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't have anything to do with the `login_required` decorator or jinja2, the problem is in your view. You should use the [`render`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/shortcuts/#render) shortcut instead of `render_to_response`.

```
from django.shortcuts import render

@login_required()
def displaystats(request):
    ...
    return render(request, 'displaystats.html', {'listpackages': listpackages})
```

When you use `render_to_response` you have to explicitly use a `RequestContext` so that the auth context processor runs and includes `user` in the template context. The `render` shortcut does it automatically.

Comment: Oh yes it works with `render` .    And thanks for explanation, it could be helpful :)